# Count the rows of columns with varied length in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, count

I have a data frame with 100 columns with varied lengths from 25 to 500 rows. I am trying to count the number of rows of several specific columns. It looks kind of like this:

```
    Col1   Col2   Col3
1     25     23     20
2     22     28     20
3     35     33     30
4     NA     40     41
5     NA     NA     43
```

If I use

```
rows = nrows (mydatafrom$col1)
```

it returns NA.

```
rows = NROWs (mydataframe)
```

returns the number of rows of the longest column.

I am also wondering whether the blank cells in the dataframe shown as NA is causing some problems. I prepared the data in Excel and used read.csv to import it into R. The empty cells are shown as NA in R.
Is there any way I count the rows of individual columns of this dataframe? I am very new to R programming and get stuck by this problem.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `nrow`, `NROW`? Note that "Col1" is not the same as "col1". Please also have a look at `?data.frame`: "A data frame is a list of variables of the **same number of rows** with unique row names"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are looking for method of counting not NA values in given column you can use:

```
length(na.omit(mydatafrom$col1))
```

or

```
sum(! is.na(mydatafrom$col1))
```

Comment: Works perfectly for my purpose! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for:

```
sapply(mydataframe,function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
```

Technically, we wouldn't refer to this situation as your data frame having columns with different number of rows. The data frame only has *one* number of rows. You're really just counting how many non-missing values there are in each column.

Comment: Thx a lot for the suggestion. Good to know the right way of describe the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
colSums(!is.na(mydataframe))
```